# Ranking and scores in Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE) in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand how to read `grid_scores_` and `ranking_` values in [RFECV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html). Here is the main example from the documentation:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.svm import SVR
X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)
estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
selector.support_ 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

selector.ranking_
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 5])
```

How am I supposed to read `ranking_` and `grid_scores_`? Is the **lower** the ranking **value** the better? (or viceversa?). The reason why ask this is because I have noticed that the features with the **highest ranking** value, have typically the highest scores in `grid_scores_`.

**However, if something has a `ranking = 1` shouldn't  that mean that it was ranked as the best of the group?**. This is also what the documentation [says](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html):

> "*Selected (i.e., estimated best) features are assigned rank 1*"

But now let's look at the following example using some real data:

```
> rfecv.grid_scores_[np.nonzero(rfecv.ranking_ == 1)[0]]
0.0
```

while the feature with the **highest** ranking **value** has the **highest** **score**.

```
> rfecv.grid_scores_[np.argmax(rfecv.ranking_ )]
0.997
```

Note that in the example above, the features with **ranking=1** have the lowest score

### Figure in the documentation:

On this matter, in [this figure](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#example-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py) in the documentation, the `y` axis reads `"number of misclassifications"`, but it is plotting `grid_scores_` which used `'accuracy'` (?) as a scoring function. Shouldn't the `y` label read `accuracy`? (**the higher the better**) instead of `"number of misclassifications"` (**the lower the better**)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct in that a low ranking value indicates a good feature and that a high cross-validation score in the `grid_scores_` attribute is also good, however you are misinterpreting what the values in `grid_scores_` mean. From the RFECV documentation

```
grid_scores_

array of shape [n_subsets_of_features]

The cross-validation scores such that grid_scores_[i] corresponds to the CV score of the i-th subset of features.
```

Thus the `grid_scores_` values don't correspond to a particular feature, they are the cross-validation error metrics for *subsets* of features. In the example the subset with 5 features turns out to be the most informative set because the 5th value in `grid_scores_` (the CV value for the SVR model incorporating the 5 most highly ranked features) is the largest.

You should also note that since the scoring metric is not explicitly specified, the scorer used is the default for SVR, which is R^2, not accuracy (which is only meaningful for classifiers).